# how to check there is no dues in the following cte

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, stored-procedures, common-table-expression

the CTE works awesomely but i don't know where to put put if condition if the sale is first
i want sum function  works in that case if the their is more than 1 debit against each accountid

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[counter_bills] @SDate date,
                                       @enddate date
AS
BEGIN;

    WITH
    CUST AS
        (SELECT customer.customername,
                customer.customercontact,
                customer.customeraddress,
                account.account_id,
                account.account_type,
                customer.customerid
         FROM account
              JOIN customer ON customer.customerid = account.customerid),
    journal AS
        (SELECT SUM(journal_entry.debit) - SUM(journal_entry.credit) AS [dues],
                journal_entry.account_id AS [journal account id]
         FROM journal_entry
         GROUP BY journal_entry.account_id),
    SALES AS
        (SELECT sale.saleid,
                sale.totalpaid,
                Stock.itemname AS item,
                invoice.saleprice AS SalePrice,
                invoice.qty,
                invoice.StockID AS [invoice Stock id],
                invoice.saleprice AS [invoice saleprice],
                sale.date,
                Stock.size,
                sale.customerid AS [cust sale id ]
         FROM invoice
              JOIN Stock ON invoice.StockID = Stock.StockID
              JOIN sale ON invoice.saleid = sale.saleid
              JOIN Our_orders ON Stock.orderID = Our_orders.orderID
              JOIN vendor ON Our_orders.VendorID = vendor.VendorID
         WHERE sale.date BETWEEN @SDate AND @enddate)
    SELECT *
    FROM CUST
         RIGHT JOIN SALES ON CUST.customerid = SALES.[cust sale id ]
         LEFT JOIN journal ON journal.[journal account id] = CUST.account_id
    ORDER BY SALES.SaleID DESC;
END;
```

Comment: `IF` isn't an expression in T-SQL, it's a Logic operator: If these conditions are true, do these operations, Else do these operations. You can't put an `IF` in the middle of a statement, so I'm not sure what the problem is you're trying to solve.

Comment: On a different note, **good** use of Aliases, White Space and Line break will makes your query far easier to read. What you have these is quite messy and difficult to understand. (I've done some formatted, but i suggest you start using aliases.) Also, using `*` in a persisted object is a bad idea as well. `*` doesn't isn't a magic "all columns" operator, and it's behaviour changes depending on the object type and can result in unexpected behaviour when the underlying objects are changed.